# Simple Dropdownbox Select in meteor helpers

Tags: javascript, meteor, dropdownbox, meteor-helper

I'm creating a simple dropdownbox using select tag and templates as shown below:

```
<template name="serviceTypes">
<select id="servicetypes">
    {{#each serviceNames}} 
       <option>{{name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

and in .js file

```
    Template.serviceTypes.helper({
    serviceNames : function () {
        var names = [{name: Yoga}, {name: Dance}];
        return names;
    } 
});
```

But still the dropdown seems to be empty.

{{still a newbie in meteor}}

Comment: there are a bunch of typos in your .js file's code. `helper` should be `helpers` and the names you have typed don't include quotation marks to make them strings. Are they just typos here or are they in your code as well?

Comment: Ohhh yeah, helpers and "" made it work !!
Thanks